# Change the font color and font type of an attachment content using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, pdfbox-layout

I'm currently working on adding an attachment to a PDF using the PDFBox library in Java. While referring to the code snippet,   [Adding a File Attachment](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithattachments.html#:%7E:text=Adding%20a%20File%20Attachment,attached%20to%20the%20document%20catalog.)

I successfully attached the document created using ByteArrayInputStream to the attachment. However, I noticed that the font type and color of the attachment's contents remain the same. How to modify the font color and type for the contents of the attachment.

The code snippet I used is as below,

```
        // create a new tree node and add the embedded file
        PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = new PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode();
        Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> treeNodeMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : keyValueMap.entrySet()) {

            // first create the file specification, which holds the embedded file
            PDComplexFileSpecification fs = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
            fs.setFile(entry.getKey());
            // create a dummy file stream, this would probably normally be a FileInputStream
            byte[] data = entry.getValue().getBytes();
            ByteArrayInputStream fakeFile = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);              
            // now lets some of the optional parameters
            PDEmbeddedFile ef = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, fakeFile);
            ef.setSubtype("text/plain");
            ef.setSize(data.length);
            ef.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            fs.setEmbeddedFile(ef);
            treeNodeMap.put(entry.getKey(), fs);
        }

        efTree.setNames(treeNodeMap);

        // add the tree to the document catalog
        PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(doc.getDocumentCatalog());
        names.setEmbeddedFiles(efTree);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setNames(names);
```

Also I would like to know if it is possible to add image and tables in the attachment along with other contents using pdfBox library . I am using 2.0.25 version of pdf box

Comment: How is all of this related to "attachment"? From what I understand, you want to change the font in an existing PDF, and add images and tables. (PDF isn't really made for editing, such changes are incredibly difficult, it's better to get the original WORD or whatever file)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Currently I have an api which generate the customers report pdf using pdfBox . I want to add an attachment file of pdf format to the same customers report pdf with some content on it. Most of the time the content inside the attachment is some plain text. What I want is to change the color and font type of attachment  as I do it for the main pdf document ( pdPageContentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE, 35) )

Comment: For starters, have you tried to change `PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE` to something else, e.g. `PDType1Font.HELVETICA` and set the color with `setNonStrokingColor(Color.red)`? I still don't see how this is related to "attachment".

Comment: Don't assume you can simply change font and color of text in an existing pdf. Under certain benign circumstances (the pdf being built in certain ways, the replacement font matching the original one in some aspects) it is possible to some degree but to verify that your pdfs allow that, we'd need representative examples. *Adding* stuff, on the other hand, usually is easy.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I tried by adding the color setNonStrokingColor(Color.red) and font PDType1Font.HELVETICA but it is applicable only in case of the parent document. It will not work for the attachment contents. To answer your question how it is related to attachments even the font color and type is applicable for a pdf attachment as well. I am not sure the issue is coming because the file type in the above code is text/plain. I have an issue related to creating pdf type attachments , sometimes this will fix once fix the issue with pdf attachment -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442124

Comment: Ah, I missed the "text/plain" part. Text files are just that. If you have seen a PDF where the text/plain attachment can be shown in different colors, please upload it somewhere, I'd have a look at it with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr I assume text/plain cannot be shown with a different font color and type. It will always use the default from the editor we use. And most of the time default is Arial Black with font size 11.  But I am sure it will render with color and specified font type in 'application/pdf ' file type. But I am not able to render a 'application/pdf ' document attachment. It is giving some error as you can see in  stackoverflow.com/questions/76442124  Will you able to provide an input on that issue